# Spring Boot - Issue while using s:mvcUrl tag

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm developing the simple Spring MVC application with aim of Spring Boot.

I've added to my new jsp new `mvcUrl` tag:

`<a href="${spring:mvcUrl('BMVCC#path').arg(0,'account').arg(1, '23').build()}">Account</a>`

When this page is being requested I get next exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: endpointHandlerMapping,requestMappingHandlerMapping
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MvcUriComponentsBuilder.getRequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping(MvcUriComponentsBuilder.java:340)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMappingName(MvcUriComponentsBuilder.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)`
```

So `mvcUrl` tag tries to get mapping handler bean but Spring Boot has 2 beans: from Spring MVC module and Spring Boot Actuator module.

Does anybody has the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the same issue.  To me it sounds like a bug in spring webmvc.